# Corona SDK Global Table not visible in Module

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I am having trouble referencing a global table in the Corona SDK.

```
--main.lua
_G.settings = 
{
    WIDTH = display.contentWidth,
    HEIGHT = display.contentHeight,
}
print(_G.settings.WIDTH)
=> 320



--module1.lua
print(_G.settings.WIDTH)
=> nil
```

I'm not sure why module1.lua is nil while it works in main.lua is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works for me. I can not reproduce your error.

NOTICE:

If you create global variable in Lua for example `myVariable` you have access to it by global table `_G`

```
_G.myVariable
```

or by its name

```
myVariable
```

So may be you have changed variable  `settings` somewhere (in main.lua or module1.lua)?

I also recommended you read about [global variables](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2013/05/28/tutorial-goodbye-globals/) in Lua.